# using pandas to write into excel file on mac with python 3.6

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to write a function that writes into an Excel file using pandas module in python on a mac computer. However, I am getting the error message:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

pandas is properly installed, I installed it via:

```
pip install pandas
```

any ideas as to why my code will not run?

```
import pandas as pd

def excel_write():
    #create dataframe
    dataframe_date = pd.DataFrame({'Date':[20170712, 20170715, 20170722]})

    #create Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlswriter')

    #convert the dataframe to XlsWriter Excel object
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='LTL Invoices')

    #close Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file
    writer.save()

excel_write()
```

Comment: Do you have python 2.7 and python 3 both installed on PC?

Comment: No, just python 3.6

Comment: in any case try installing `pandas` with `pip3 install pandas`. Might work=)

Comment: i am using Sierra 10.12.4

Comment: no, you stated `pip install pandas`, not `pip3`

Comment: yeah sorry i wasn't reading carefully, i tried that and now i am getting an error message that says ValueError: No Excel writer 'xlswriter'

Answer (score 1):

Ok, now that you finally installed `pandas`, as far as I understand, you actually don't need any freaky functions to write to `excel`.

When you have your `DataFrame` ready to write, just simply use:

`df.to_excel(your_dataframe, sheet_name='LTL Invoices')`

If you still want to proceed your way, try to replace `xlswriter` to `xlsxwriter`:

```
import pandas as pd

def excel_write():
    # Create a Pandas dataframe from the data.
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':[20170712, 20170715, 20170722]})

    # Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

    # Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='LTL Invoices')

    # Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
    writer.save()

excel_write()
```